# Dynamically allocate and free memory in local functions

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

Consider the following function:

```
void free_or_not ( int count ) {
    int i ;
    int *ip = malloc ( count * sizeof ( int ) ) ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++ )
        ip[i] = i ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < count ; i ++ )
        printf ( "%d\n" , ip[i] ) ;

    free ( ip ) ;
}
```

Will this cause memory leak if I don't call `free()` inside `free_or_not()`?

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory on the heap, which does not magically vanish when a function terminates. Magically vanishing is the stack memory's job.

Comment: @Mints97 your point is what I actually posted this question for. very nice job indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,when your function finishes, you will lose the pointer to the allocated memory to free() it.

Answer (score 7):

> *Will this cause memory leak if I don't call `free()` inside `free_or_not()`?*

Yes, it will cause memory leak. Once your function finishes execution, you don't have any *pointers* to the allocated memory to `free()` it.

**Solution:** If you change the return type of your function to `void *` (or similar) and return the allocated pointer (`ip`)from the function, then, you can collect that pointer tn the caller and `free()` the pointer from the caller of this function.

Comment: You can also store the returned pointer in some previously allocated memory block, thus building a *dynamically linked* data structure. A common example are dynamically linked lists and trees. After use, you can remove (un-link) a specific part from the list and free it, or release the whole structure by following those stored pointers and iteratively or recursively freeing a block after block.